# assign a consecutive ID for rows with specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to assign a consecutive ID for rows with specified value in my case `Identifier` and ideally in ascending order by `Value`?

The  table should look like this:

```
Identifier      ID  Name        Value
identifier1     1   example1    value100
identifier1     2   example2    value200
identifier1     3   example3    value400
identifier2     1   example3    value100
identifier2     2   example5    value500
identifier3     1   example11   value600
identifier3     2   example12   value800
```

My code so far only gives a consecutive ID for the whole Table `#Temp`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
        Identifier          NVARCHAR(256)
    ,   ID  INT NOT NULL    IDENTITY( 1, 1)
    ,   Name                NVARCHAR(256)
    ,   Value               NVARCHAR(256)
    )

WHILE Condition
BEGIN


SELECT @Identifier  = Identifier    (..)
SELECT @Table       = Table         (..)

SET @Sql = N'
        SELECT  
        ''' + @Identifier + '''
    ,   Name
    ,   MAX(Value)
        FROM ' + @Table+ ' WITH (NOLOCK)
        GROUP BY Name
        ORDER BY Name
        '

    INSERT INTO #Temp
    EXEC ( @Sql )
END
```

Comment: First of all you do not need dynamic sql here, and a loop is the wrong approach. And that NOLOCK hint is an extra layer of frustration you don't want to add. Your posted pseudocode has abstracted the problem so much it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to assign consecutive id’s to each group of rows with the same identifier. All you need is ROW_NUMBER()

### Adding ID’s with ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Identifier ORDER BY [Value]),*
From YourTable
```